# Twisted screening operators and twisted free-field realizations of $\mathcal{W}_n$ algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, conformal-field-theory, vertex-algebras, w-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{sl}_{n+1}$ and I am interested in the principal $\mathcal{W}$-algebra of $\mathcal{g}$ at self-dual level i.e. $k=- h ^{\vee} +1$, usually denoted by $\mathcal{W}_n$. Now these VOAs can be realized as subalgebras inside the rank $n$ Heisenberg (free boson) VOA. It can also be realized as the intersection of the kernels of screening operators,
$$\mathcal{W}_n \cong \cap \mathrm{Ker} Q_{\alpha}$$
where the screening operators are obtained as integrals of vertex operators for every simple root $\alpha$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ (scaled by some number $k_{\alpha}$),
$$Q_{\alpha}= \int \exp \left( k_{\alpha}\alpha \right).$$

In particular these screening operators map highest weight Fock space states to singular vectors of $\mathcal{W}_n$. I am interested in "twisted" generalization of this picture. For simplicity let $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{sl}_3$. Let $H$ be a rank 2 Heisenberg algebra. Then we can construct a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-twisted Fock module, $M$ (See for example [Doyon](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0611120) for the definition of twisted modules.) generated by integer and half-integer modes $\{J_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}/2}$ instead of just integer modes. Note that $M$ upon restriction to $\mathcal{W}_3$ is an untwisted-module as it lies in the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ orbifold.

**Question:**
Is there a generalization of the above picture for twisted modules?

1. Can I construct screening operators from twisted vertex operators and in what sense will these yield singular vectors?
2. Does the intersection of these twisted screenings produce a free-field realization of $\mathcal{W}_3$ inside the Heisenberg algebra?

Comment: Could you explicit what you mean by "twisted vertex operator"? You mention a generalization to twisted modules, but notice that in the usual case the "vertex operator" $exp(a)$ are not vertex operators coming from a module structure for the Heisenberg algebra. Do you mean the same exponential formula with the twisted Boson instead of the usual one?

Comment: @ReimundoHeluani: Yes that's exactly what I mean. Something like $Y(a,z) \approx \exp\left(\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}/2} \frac{a_n}{n} z^{-n}\right)$. Such operators appear as intertwining operators of twisted modules of the Heisenberg. For example, in this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0310425